# Withdrawal of 457 visa

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, australia, long-stay-visas, victoria-australia

What are the steps to stop processing of an Australia 457 visa if applied from a company? I need directions as I may get a 190 visa granted before the 457.

Comment: Questions about work visas such as 457 should be better addressed at [expats.SE](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com).